# Make selection from database faster laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I wish to know how to select data from database faster and efficiently because I am working with a single page application which show data from database before page is loaded so I wrote a code for selecting from database in `route.php` in Laravel like below.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $image = DB::table('imagedetails')->select('tittle', 'content','filename','album')->get();
    $project = DB::table('projects')->select('projecttittle', 'contentofprojects','imageofprojects','extension')->get();
    return view('index')->with('imagedet',$image)
       ->with('project',$project);
});
```

But I am afraid that if the content in the database table increases it will affect the page loading time.

Please kindly help me to understand the better way.

Comment: You cannot just assume _it will be slower_ before checking an actual slow process ?! What if Laravel worked so hard to provide an already efficient facade such as `DB` ?

Comment: you mean this is best way

Comment: What is cool with Laravel is you can do something with different ways, and still get the same result. I would recommend using `DB` facade as it is a convenient and general way to perform query in a database. Some others will like having a model to use their table, but the result is the same : this is the same engine that perform the query (PDO if I am not wrong), and many optimizations come around to let you get your resultat as fast as possible. It is the meaning of a framework, only focus on your job, not the optimizations/secure part.

Comment: OK thanks for clarification.I will do it as you suggested

Comment: can you please help me to know that what is the use of events in laravel

Comment: If it is not related to databases, please check if your question has not been answered yet, or fill in a question to ask others PhP developpers for help :)